# Workload Identity Federation_GCP: Connection Error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, workload-identity, gcp-config-connector

I'm trying to access GCP resources from an application which is deployed in AWS using Workload Identity Federation. So I set the config file in environmental variable (like how we do with normal service account key) but its not connecting and sending me an error message.

I've added the snippet of error message below:

//error message//

{ "message": "\n\n<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">\n \n  404 - Not Found\n \n \n

## 404 - Not Found

\n \n\n" }

//

I'm not sure why this is happening. Could someone assist me on this please?

Comment: Your question has no details and you are assuming that we know what you set up. Edit your question with details.

Comment: Add details on the configuration and how you perform your test.

Comment: @JohnHanley Could you please let me know what are the details you want? so that I can update the question completely.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I've downloaded the config file and set them in environmental variable. I followed the same method as how we set credentials of normal service account key. I ran the test using postman..